# Can I add data from a cell on sheet 2 to a cell on sheet 3?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to grab the total of the # hours from 6 cells in a row on sheet 2, and add them and the total of a cell on sheet 3, and display the result in another cell on sheet 3. What I have tried is:
=+Sheet2!CV2:DA2+B2 in the cell I want the data displayed.
What I get is a #VALUE! in the cell.
I had a week long class a number of years ago on Excel, so I have been struggling with this whole project. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps remove the + from before Sheet2! unless it is part of the formula.

If I sum 6 cells on Sheet2, I need the formula:

```
=SUM(Sheet2!B3:B8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start in the cell on sheet 3 where you want the sum to appear and enter "=SUM(" then use the mouse to select the first cell or range (block of adjacent cells) you want to add up. Type a comma, then select the next cell or range, and once you've selected the last cell or range, just press enter and it should jump back to sheet 3 and show you the sum.

Comment: OK I did as you suggested, =SUM(Sheet3!CJ32:CO32,B32), in cell B33 on sheet 3, but it only shows a "#" in the cell now. If I hover my mouse over B33 I an see the number that should be in that cell. Also, why does it show sheet3 in the formula when I got cells CJ2-CO2 from sheet2? I tried typing sheet2 to see if that made a difference, but it did not.

Comment: @sherswan Put the cursor on that cell, right click, and select "Format cells..." When the box opens up, select "General" at the top of the list on the first tab.